# Difference between Product(Standard Price book) and Product (Saturn Price book) related list on Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, pricebook, product

**Difference between Product(Standard Price book) and Product (Saturn Price book) related list on Opportunity** -

On some Opportunity I see  Product(Standard Price book) related list and on some I see Product(Saturn Price book)related list, why is it so ?

(Never worked on this yet.)

If I have to have Product (Standard Price Book) related list with "Add Product" button on Opportunity, what should be the steps ?

Answer (score 2):

Saturn Price Book is a custom Price Book. Standard Price Book is as the name suggests, is the standard Price Book containing all Products and their standard price.

An opportunity can only have one Price Book selected at a time. It is possible to have the Price Book defaulted by some other configuration/customisation in your org so the user does not need to make a conscious decision to select it each time.

You can change Price Books, but doing this will remove all Opportunity Products as you cannot mix Pricebooks on a single Opportunity.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you ! It helps. But 
again what are all the possible ways/steps for this statement you mentioned in an answer -  "possible to have the Price Book defaulted by some other configuration/customisation"


One I could tell is - Goto - Price Book -> Create new "Standar Price Book" & Share it with only particular User/Role/Profile, etc. 

So, likewise - what could be other ways ?

Comment: If the user has only one Pricebook enabled for them, then this will be the defaulted in for all opportunities. The other ways are using Apex or declarative tools like PB/flow. This link will help http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7935/is-it-possible-to-default-a-pricebook-based-on-the-recordtype